# Flutter 2: From List null safety create a children row with mapIndex

Tags: list, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Since the update of flutter of null safety I don't understand anything of what is happening.

I am trying from a list on a children to create a Row of icons but I don't succeed (here the mapIndex can't be used because of the null safety (whereas in an older version it would worked)):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>>? icons;

  const NavigationBar({
    @required this.icons,
    Key? key
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavigationBarState createState() => _NavigationBarState();
}

class _NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 40,
      child: Row(
        children: widget.icons.mapIndex((i, icon) {return Container();})
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "whereas in an older version it would worked" ... `List` has no method named `mapIndex`.  It's not clear to me what that's supposed to do.  Anyway, `icons` is nullable, so you must check that it isn't `null` before calling methods on it.  If you're confused about null safety, please read https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was the missing of the collection import (so I couldn't use mapIndex)

The second is the verification of the null. I don't know if it is the better solution but here my version where I check the null value :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class NavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>>? icons;

  const NavigationBar({
    @required this.icons,
    Key? key
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavigationBarState createState() => _NavigationBarState();
}

class _NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 12, 10, 10),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 40,
      child: Row(
        children: widget.icons == null ? [] :
          widget.icons!.mapIndexed((index, element) =>
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: widget.icons![0]['icon'],
            color: Colors.white,
          )).toList()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For null safety first, check the variable is null or not.

```
widget.icons!.map((e) => Container(child: Text(e.keys.toString()),)).toList()
```

Full Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class NavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>>? icons;

  const NavigationBar({
    @required this.icons,
    Key? key
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavigationBarState createState() => _NavigationBarState();
}

class _NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 40,
      child: Row(
          children: widget.icons!.map((e) => Container(child: Text(e.keys.toString()),)).toList()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I really need the mapIndex .map is not enought

Comment: do you need an index?  widget.icons!.indexOf(e)

Comment: No I need to have an index and an element as the method mapIndex, because I'll compare a local index to the index proposed in mapIndex and depending of that I'll show the element of mapIndex

Comment: Using `!` isn't appropriate to "check if a variable is null or not".  It is an *assertion* that a variable is not null; the application should crash if that assertion isn't true.

Comment: Yes I know (in my cas it wouldn't be null but what I want is use mapIndex with this List null safety and why not without using `!`) Oh and I juste understood your response Hasib, but no I don't want to use `widget.icons!.indexOf(e)` it is a waste of performances and if I use it the element would be a widget so it is an hard waste of performances.

Comment: Ok so here I am juste dumb it was missing the : import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; but now how implement it using the null safety with `?` ?